# Update statement inside a while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a program which needs to insert the calculated value from another table.

For example the user inputted "2"

First the user will search the all the records under the Quantity Required Column. And after searching, the program will automatically multiply all the quantity required by "2"

I used update statement because the table has a default value of zero

here is my code:

```
$num = $_POST['qtytoorder']; 
$sql = "select qtyrqrd from bom_inventory where boardmodel ='$boardname'";
$result =@mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $qty = $row['qtyrqrd'];
    $res = $qty * $num;
    echo $res;
    //insert new records for qtyneeded via update statement
    $insert ="update bom_inventory set qtyneeded='$res', qty2complete =$res where boardmodel ='$boardname'";
    @mysql_query($insert,$connect)or die("Failed to execute query:<br />" . mysql_error(). "<br />" . mysql_errno());
}
```

There is no error in my code while I am running it but my problem is I am only getting the last multiplied quantity. I want to insert all the multiplied quantity.

Comment: Quick response not sure about rest but this `qty2complete =$res`  should be `qty2complete = '$qty'`

Comment: Is the echo giving the right numbers or are they incorrect too ?

Comment: Remember that using `@mysql_query` will suppress your error messages.

Comment: @Uchiha If you're looking then you can see $qty is the number before it's multiplied by the user input

Comment: @Djip the echo is giving the right numbers

Comment: @MyrtsGrc You know that you're inserting the value at the same place all the time. where boardmodel ='$boardname'. This is because i guess this isn't unique like a id or such. I suggest you make a unique id column in the table and then something like: select id ,qtyrqrd from bom_inventory where boardmodel ='$boardname' and then make the insert like: $id = $row['id'] and update bom_inventory set qtyneeded='$res', qty2complete =$res where id ='$'

Answer (score 0):

So after all the talking forth and back this is the result i guess

```
$num = $_POST['qtytoorder']; 
$sql = "select id, qtyrqrd from bom_inventory where boardmodel ='$boardname'";
$result =@mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $qty = $row['qtyrqrd'];
    $res = $qty * $num;
    $id = $num['id'];
    echo $res;
    //insert new records for qtyneeded via update statement
    $insert ="update bom_inventory set qtyneeded='$res', qty2complete =$res where id ='$id'";
    @mysql_query($insert,$connect)or die("Failed to execute query:<br />" . mysql_error(). "<br />" . mysql_errno());
}
```

Gladly i could help you out :)